# Are there unwanted untrimmed usernames?

Tags: bug, status-completed

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/users/935343/henry) user seems to have untrimmed username.

```
<td style="width:230px" class="fn nickname"><b>Henry </b></td>
```

Is that normal/by-design or is it really minor bug?

Comment: How did you discover that?

Comment: @jjnguy [Jquery update all browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351718/7351807#comment-8869357)

Comment: oh, neat!  That does look odd.

Comment: @jjnguy maybe it is untrimmed for unregistered users?

Comment: I tried to add a space and a tab to the end of my name.  It didn't work.

Comment: @jjnguy odd a bit more.

Comment: Wow, what's the reason for that downvote? Is it wrong?

Comment: Disagreement, he probably only read your question title and doesn't want untrimmed usernames.

Comment: @TomWijsman: ah, probably. edited

Comment: `status-bydesign`

Comment: @0A0D: I think so too, given that user profile pages also don't trim it (see the HTML).

Comment: @jjinguy: Interesting, perhaps people were able to do it on a certain date or in the initial entry form but no longer able to do it in the current profile editor? In which case it could be a bug where it's not consistent everywhere...

Comment: @Tom: Well he just became a member today, last seen 37 mins ago.

Comment: @0A0D: Ah, right; we can still compare the initial entry form against the current profile name edit form.

Comment: @Tom: I tried editing, spaces were stripped.

Comment: So, the entry form for unregistered users has a bug.

Comment: @TomWijsman: yes, that's correct

Comment: I don't see how this is an issue. Since you can have the same display name as someone else, it's not like you need this as a workaround.

Comment: @quantumSoup: read tags: [minor-annoyances]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could happen on *unregistered* users previously.  It no longer can in the next build...and we'll trim any existing ones after that goes out.